# Tips on golfing this Python program to generate a palindrome from a string

Tags: code-golf, tips, python, palindrome

I wrote this function in 48 bytes and I wonder, is there any way to write this code 2 characters shorter?

```
p=lambda n,c:(n*c)[:n//2]+(n*c)[:n//2+n%2][::-1]
```

The point of the function is to create a palindrome of length `n` by using all the characters from the string `c`. Example: `n = 3`, `c = 'ab'`. Result is `'aba'`.

Is there something I am missing that can be shortened or is there no other way to make it shorter? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! I've cleaned up your question a bit to be closer to our standards (changed the title, added some correct tags). Feel free to edit anything you dislike

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit! :)

Comment: If you need to use all of `c`, why is `n` necessary?  I can see if that's the control for whether or not the palindrome has a central, unmatched character (odd number of output) or if each character is paired up (even number of chars).  But what would you want the output to be for `n=9, c="ab"` or `n=3, c="abdefg"`?

Comment: Why, _precisely_, 2 bytes shorter?

Comment: @Shaggy This is a [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/58b57f984f353b3dc9000030) problem, A 2-byte improvement would be needed to pass in Python.

Answer (score 6):

In general, slicing twice usually results in extraneous code.

Here, you use `[:n//2+n%2][::-1]`. The first part means "get from `0` to `n//2+n%2`", left-inclusive right-exclusive. The second part reverses it. Thus, what you are *actually* trying to do is get from `n//2+n%2-1` to `-1`, stepping by `-1`, left-inclusive right-exclusive. Thus, you can do `[n//2-n%2-1:-1:-1]`. The stop argument is excessive there.

```python
p=lambda n,c:(n*c)[:n//2]+(n*c)[n//2+n%2-1::-1]
```

Then, since `n%2-1` gives `0` for odd numbers and `-1` for even numbers, we can also get `0` for odd numbers and `1` for even numbers via `~n%2`, and then subtract that:

```python
p=lambda n,c:(n*c)[:n//2]+(n*c)[n//2-~n%2::-1]
```

(The following is found by dingledooper)

Finally, we can optimize that part even further, as what we are asking for is `n//2-1` for even numbers and `n//2` for odd numbers. Notice that if we subtract one, then `(n-1)//2` solves this. For integers, `n-1` is equivalent to `~-n` (remember that `~` is complement, and `~n == -1 - n` so `~-n == -1 + n == n - 1`). Therefore, we can shorten that part down to `[~-n//2::-1]`.

Remember the `~-` trick for decrementing (as well as `-~` for incrementing) as it saves 2 bytes for `(n+1)` and `(n-1)` where brackets would otherwise be needed, since unary operators have very high precedence.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

```python
p=lambda n,c:(n*c)[:n//2]+(n*c)[~-n//2::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8A2JzE3KSVRIU8n2UojTytZM9oqT1/fKFYbwqnTBfGsrHQNY/8XFGXmlWgUaBga6CgoJSYpaWpywYWMwUIpicVpKcjipkDhlOL0xPSUtHSg@H8A)

(Thanks to Jo King for spotting this one)

If you can use Python 3.8, inline assignment with the walrus operator saves a byte:

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 42 bytes

```python
p=lambda n,c:(r:=n*c)[:n//2]+r[~-n//2::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8A2JzE3KSVRIU8n2UqjyMo2TytZM9oqT1/fKFa7KLpOF8SystI1jP1fUJSZV6JRoGFooKOglJikpKnJBRcyBgulJBanpSCLmwKFU4rTE9NT0tKB4v8B)

Comment: Yes, exactly 2 characters! Incredible idea, thank you so much!

Comment: I've checked out `n//2-~n%2`, and seems to be equal to `~-n//2` (that's a 3 byte save).

Comment: @dingledooper Oh yeah, that makes sense. Thank you, I will include that and add an explanation.